# Why would SmtpClient behave differently on XP/Vista/Win7

Tags: c#, .net, gmail, smtpclient

I'm using the following code which appears to work perfectly every time on Vista/Win7.

```
private void SendEmail(string subject, string body, string attach)
{
    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage("username@gmail.com", "username@gmail.com", subject, body))
    {
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attach))
        {
            Attachment attached = new Attachment(attach);
            message.Attachments.Add(attached);
        }

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password"),
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        };

        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

However on Windows XP I'm getting:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refuses it
```

I've checked and Windows firewall is completely disabled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try from the Windows machine the following:

1. <kbd>windows key + r</kbd>
2. Type `cmd`
3. Type `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`

If it says connection refused or similar then it's a firewall or network problem, unrelated with the code.

Comment: telnet fails. For some reason this happens with all our XP machines and none of the Vista Win7 ones. I'll have to see what they all have installed...

Comment: But note that `telnet.exe` isn't installed by default on some versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say if this is it, but we had that problem at one point, and it was an antivirus utility that was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same version of System.Net.Mail on all three systems ?

Also, could be related to the Windows Firewall blocking connections (or some other firewall).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this has anything to do with the OS, that type of exception is usually bubbled up from inner ones. Trap the exception and have a look into the inner exceptions and see what the real problem is.

However, this sort of problem is usually a firewall blockage, the remote smtp server is blocking incoming requests or your machine is blocking outgoing requests on port 25.